# Question about convergence involving uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory

$X_{1}$ is chosen at random from [0,1] and for n=2$\dots$ $X_{n}$ is chosen at random from $[0,X_{n-1}]$.
Show that $\lim_{n \to\infty}P(\sqrt[n]{X_{n}}\geq e^{-t})=0,t<1$
$and =1,t>1$ .

My solution

Set $U_{n}=\frac{X_{n}}{X_{n-1}}$ uniformly distributed on [0,1] and independent from $X_{1}\dots X_{n-1}$ ,so
$X_{n}=X_{1}*\frac{X_{2}}{X_{1}}*\dots * 
\frac{X_{n-1}}{X_{n-2}}*\frac{X_{n}}{X_{n-1}}$

Then $P(X_{n}>e^{-nt})=P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}logU_{i}>-nt)$ ,so from the strong law since $E(logU)=-1$ we get the desirable result.

Another solution comes from the central limit theorem.

My question focus on my first assumption involving the uniform distribution.

Comment: Why is $U_n$ independent of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$?

Comment: not from $X_{n}$ i have to edit that

Comment: thats my assumption  ,my thought is that if we divide each random variable with the previous one the support is [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

I think your intuition is correct.

One way to sidestep the problen of checking the independence of the $U_n$ issue is to *posit* that the $U_n$ are an iid sequence of $U[0,1]$ rvs, and then *check* that the distribution of the products $U_1, U_1U_2, U_1U_2U_3, ...$ is what was claimed for $X_1, X_2, ...$.

Comment: ok,i will chek it thanks for the answer